# C# Json serialization backing field references property instead of the other way round

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, field

I use NewtonSoft.Json latest version and need to serdes third-party objects. I need to serialize *fields*. Here is the JsonSerializerSettings which I use:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings_ = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
    ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(),
};
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        properties = properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName != "MonitoringInstance" && p.PropertyName != "SessionInstance").ToList();
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(f => CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization));
        return properties.Union(fields, new EqualityComparer()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, no matter how I tried, the backing field references the Property. Is there anyway to reverse it? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to simply decorate your class with `DataContractAttribute` and the fields with `DataMemberAttribute`. Unless you really want to implement the contract resolver yourself this is what we do all the time with JSON.

Comment: It's third-party objects

Comment: How do you know that your third party objects are serializable in the first place? Depending on how big they are it might make sense to copy said objects into serializable DTOs.

Comment: It has [Serializable] attribute. It's big. So, DTO is counter-productive.

Comment: The corresponding property is properly serialized but the backing field is null.